# How to fix SIGEMT on pandas import in PyCharm?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pycharm, interrupt

When I import pandas on newly created virtualenv and install pandas, PyCharm finishes code execution (without actually executing anything) with *SIGEMT* error. Same problem appears if I create Anaconda-Based virtualenv and try to import pandas. But if I execute the code from terminal, or remove *import pandas*, it works normally. Full error:

```
Process finished with exit code 135 (interrupted by signal 7: SIGEMT)
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: UPD: If I use Anaconda from PyCharm directly, without using virtualenv, i face  the same issue